# Why NoSQL databases does not provide support for adhoc queries

Tags: sql, database, nosql

Suppose I have a table in a RDBMS having 26 columns, say A - Z. 
With relational databases I can writes queries which invlove  conditions on multiple columns. For example,

```
Select A, B
from table
where C > 12
and D = 'john' 
and E between 3 and 6
order by F;
```

However, if I have the same table in a NoSQL database, all they provide is lookups based on primary keys, or some predefined GSI(taking dynamodb as example).

Although, I can issue a scan against the table in NoSQL db, but that is a lot slower as compared to a table in RDBMS even if the columns involved are not indexed.

I wanted to understand what are the reasons why NoSQL databases scale very well, but fail to provide a query language like SQL. Can someone throw some lightt on it?

Comment: It's not true - see hiveQL for instance for hadoop. Also - it's not true about noSQL not allowing joins on multiple conditions - it's about cartesian product (not completely, but it's rather discouraged). Joins on multiple conditions you can do everywhere AFAIK.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a poor fit for this site - it's very broad (NoSQL is a category of products), and likely to opinion based.

Comment: I think the question could probably be re-worded to be more specific to a use case. As it is, the broad characterization is indeed inaccurate, thus it is hard to understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 2):

You should be more specific about which database(s) you're asking about. You mention DynamoDB, but it's not clear in your question whether this is one example, or are you asking *only* about DynamoDB?

There are [over 220 products that call themselves NoSQL](http://nosql-database.org), and they have different characteristics.

- Some have an SQL-*like* language, some don't.
- Some support queries to search by secondary attributes, some don't.

It's more a question of why a specific product didn't implement a SQL-like language, not a limitation of "NoSQL" as a broad category of products.

Your question is like asking "why don't non-motorcycles have a clutch?" The answer is that non-motorcycles is a broad category of vehicles, some of which actually *do* have a clutch, whereas some others were designed not to *need* a clutch.

Answer (score 0):

No-SQL databases are designed on the premise that the data contained within them is schemaless. Thus, there is no pre-defined structure for the data which a database engine can easily use to determine how to execute an ad-hoc query.  However, some no-sql database engines (e.g. [Couchbase](https://www.couchbase.com/)) do indeed offer such a capability.

The issue with database management systems in general has rarely been about storage and retrieval efficiency, but rather query plan optimization. In general, computers are not very good about dealing with issues created by poor designs. Also in general, most developers are not good at properly structuring data such that it can be queried quickly and easily by an automatically-generated query plan. Thus, most systems which rely upon automatically generated query plans tend to suffer performance issues.

In my opinion, the reason why a no-sql technology might not want to provide automatic query plan generation is that it forces the developer to give actual thought to the process of retrieving the data out, such that an efficient and effective plan might be devised in the code.  Indeed, I have found that I am usually better at writing queries than the computer is.  Could I restructure the data in such a way that the computer can write a good query plan the first time? Yes, but that takes more time than doing it myself to begin with.